# Why does one range burner only turn on when another is turned on?

Tags: switch, stove

I have a GE smooth surface stove, model JBS55DM2WW.

It has a strange switch problem. When I turn on the front right large burner it does not come on, but if I turn on any of the other burners and then turn the front right one on, it comes on.

Seems odd to me (being an electrician).

Is this a bad switch, and if so is there no switch to switch protection against feed through such as this or is it built into the switch?

Comment: Sounds like something's cross-wired. Is it under warranty? Is this a recent occurrence?

Comment: @A.I.Breveleri -- this is an electric range, not a gas stove.

Comment: Hi Daniel ,  The stove is 2 years old, I verified the wiring to be correct via the factory schematic. I decided to swap the front right switch with the rear left switch. The problem moved to the rear left burner. It's strange that the switch would fail to the point it becomes a safety problem. Very poor design by ge.  I sent ge an email explaining the problem 6 days ago and they have not responded. I have a new switch order, should be here soon.

Comment: I don't have a solution, but we have the same problem on a Frigidaire range, so it's not just GE.

Answer (score 1):

You clearly have a wiring problem.  It sounds like you have lost one phase to the burner that has the problem.  When you turn on the second/support burner, that switch is back-feeding power to the problem burner switch.

Also inherent in these kind of problems, you may be getting the 240-volt to all the switches but somehow the wiring connections or wire leads have lost the ability to carry a load. Look for burned and or worn leads and connections.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem with my Maytag electric stove. I pulled the back plate off, and on the lower left side there are two connectors that seem to be connected to a circle thing. One of them was bent slightly down all I did was bend it back straight, and it seems to completely fix the problem. Try checking the area and making sure everything is straight and looks like it should.